# DataGridView ComboBox en C#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

¿Como hacer un `combobox` para cada columna de un `datagridview`? Tengo un datagridview con 3 columnas Nombre, Cantidad y precio, y estos productos los traigo al apretar un boton desde otro formulario de esta manera:

```
foreach (Form frmFc in Application.OpenForms)
 { 
    if (frmFc.Name == "frmFactura")
    {
      frmFac = (Facturas.frmFactura)frmFc;
      frmFac.dgvIngProductos.Rows.Add(nombre, cantidad, precio);                    
      this.Close();
      break;
    }
 }
```

Pero en la columna precio tengo un `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` que se tiene que llenar con 3 precios.
No hallo la manera de llenar cada fila con los diferentes precios del idnombre que llamo. Este es el codigo:

```
public DataTable RecogerPrecios(int id)
        {
            using (var conexionN = new SqlConnection(conexionBD.ConexionBasesD())
            {
                conexionN.Open();
                using(var comando = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                    comando.Connection = conexionN;
                    comando.CommandText = "Select Precio1Prod, Precio2Prod, Precio3Prod from TablaProductos where IdProducto = @id";
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                    
                    SqlDataReader leerfilas = comando.ExecuteReader();                    
                    tabla.Load(leerfilas);
                    leerfilas.Close();
                    return tabla;
                }
            }
        }
```

Quiero que al agregar un nuevo producto el `combobox` de esa **fila 1** tenga sus 3 precios correspondientes, y si lleno otra **fila 2**, tenga sus precios correspondientes sin que la fila anterior pierda sus 3 precios. Trabajo con `C#` y `Sql Server`. Espero puedan ayudarme y orientarme.